# Jquery Prompt Button

Tags: jquery, html, function, prompt

I need a little bit of help. I'm new at jquery and I'm trying to make a button that the user clicks and then prompt appears. But No matter what I do I can't seem to get the prompt to occur after you hit the button.

HTML:

```
<input class=".button" type="submit" value="Car" />
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".button").click(function() {
            var myNumber = 19.2;
            var myAnswer = prompt("How many miles did you travel?");
            document.write("Your Carbon Foot print is:" + myAnswer * myNumber + "lbs" );

          });
      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the period from your input class `".button"` in the HTML.

Although jQuery/CSS selectors use period and hash to differentiate between `class` and `IDs`, you don't put them on the HTML element.

Comment: It's incorrect to put '#' or '.' in your class/ID attribute in HTML.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst It's not irrelevant, his target element has the class with a period prepended, not the same

Comment: My apologies, I was looking a the jQuery selector and overlooked the error with the class attribute in his HTML.